# Error not caught when saving to Realm with duplicate primaryKey

Tags: swift, error-handling, realm

I want to catch error when realm fails to write and throws an error.

I run a test which attempts to save two objects with same primaryKey(id).  Realm thorws RLMException but its not caught.

```
static func save(article: Article) -> Bool {

    do {
        let realm = try Realm()

        try realm.write {
            realm.add(article)
        }
        return true

    } catch {
        print("***** ERROR *******")
        return false
    }

}
```

I run a test like below.

```
func testDuplicateSave() {

    let id = 7777

    let a = Article()
    a.id = id
    RealmClient.save(a)



    let a2 = Article()
    a2.id = id

    let resut = RealmClient.save(a2)

    XCTAssertFalse( resut )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm indeed throws an Objective-C exception if you attempt to persist an object with an already existing primary key.

Swift's error handling doesn't catch Objective-C exceptions. It is based on an `ErrorType` return mechanism which "translates" `NSError` pointer-based APIs from Objective-C.

Throwing and catching exceptions in Objective-C should be in general avoided as it is more expensive. Unlike many other languages, it should be only done in really exceptional cases, which you can't foresee, not when you attempt an operation which is foreseeable failable as e.g. seen on I/O disk operations with `NSFileManager`.

So why does Realm throw an exception instead of failing at this place?
We consider persisting an object with an already existing primary key a programmer error. You can easily check yourself whether the primary key already exists. For that reason, we leave that up to the developer's responsibility to avoid conflating different kinds of root causes for errors.

```
static func save(article: Article) -> Bool {
    // Opening a Realm fails if the file is inaccessible on the file
    // system, it has a different schema version, it is encrypted
    // and you don't provide matching credentials or the virtual
    // address space is exhausted. If you don't provide explicit
    // error handling for any of this cases at this place, then
    // you can open the Realm by a force-try without hesitation.
    let realm = try! Realm()
    // Write transactions are mutually exclusive. So starting the
    // transaction before checking whether an object with the same
    // primary key already exists, ensures that such an object
    // can't be concurrently created by any other thread.
    realm.beginWrite()
    if let _ = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Article, article.id) {
         // Object exists already.
         realm.cancelWrite()
         return false;
    }
    realm.add(article)
    // Write transactions fail if it would cause the file to
    // outgrow the virtual address space or the disk capacity.
    // If you don't provide explicit error handling for this case
    // at this place, then you can commit the write transaction
    // by a force-try without hesitation.
    try! realm.commitWrite()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! I just wrote lines of code to avoid duplicate save.